# iPhone taking a picture when saving always landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have this iPhone application that let users take a picture and save it in a database online. My problem is that every time an user take a picture and saves it, the picture results to be in landscape, even though it was taken in portrait mode. This results in having the portrait picture stretched.

This is the code I use when taking a picture:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],1);
    UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

    if(img.size.width < img.size.height){
        NSLog(@"width < height");
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"width > height");
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 460, 320)];
    }

    imageView.image = img;
    [img release];
    [[self view] fillPreviewWithImg: imageView];
    [[self view] setImage: imageView.image];
}
```

Basically what I do is take the picture, create a UIImage, check if it's portrait or landscape, create the corresponding UIImageView and then set the image into the UIImageView. After that I just call a couple of methods to set up the image in the main view.

I believe the problem with stretching is not bounded to the PHP but to the Objective-C code, but I can't really see how or why this behavior happens.

Does anyone of you have an idea?

Thanks,

Masiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the imageOrientation property of the UIImage class.  You can have an image that is 320 wide and 480 high, but with an orientation of Landscape.  This is contained in the EXIF information and it is up to the viewing program to use this orientation information to rotate the image appropriately.  Just checking the width and height of the image is not sufficient to know the orientation and this is causing your stretching that you are seeing.

Comment: I have the logs printed correctly when I take either a landscape picture or a portrait picture, but still even though the UIImageView is created correctly, it is still stretched for portrait and correct for landscape, is that even possible? Moreover how do I use the UIImageOrientation? I've taken a look at it but it's ambiguous.

Comment: `UIImage *img=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];` Then check for the imageOrientation of this and if it is portrait, then create the imageview with the CGRect of 320,460 otherwise use 460,320.

Comment: I did something like this: `case UIImageOrientationUp:  
            NSLog(@"width < height, orientation up");
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
            break; ` and did the same for UIImageOrientationLeft and UIImageOrientationRight (for landscape). Do you think a switch would do the job? I've set my code for testing and still waiting response in the meantime.

Comment: It might be because you are getting the image in an NSData first. This could be losing some information.  Try doing `UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];` But I'm not near the SDK information so I can't check it at the moment.  I'd suggest you have a look at the Apple examples for using the camera and see if you are doing something a bit different to what they suggest.